# How to find which part of the sky a photo contains?

Tags: photography, software

I was taking some photo stacks yesterday, and I also took a plenty of random ones (pointed not at a specific object) too at 200mm.

However, I've ended with a shot but I have no idea where I pointed my camera at, and because of the narrow angle of 200mm, I'm lost without any guiding star/object.

This happened to me before too, so I was wondering whether there is a software or a website that I can upload a photo, and it will analyze the objects, cross match them with known objects and detect which part of the sky it is? Or is there a method that I can use to figure out by myself (remember that there are no well-known bright stars in the image, at least not that I can identify by myself)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried [nova.astrometry.net](http://nova.astrometry.net)?

They set up a web service for doing more or less what you're talking about.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: An amazing example of the sort of thing that modern computers/databases/connectivity can achieve.

Answer (score 2):

This type of software is called plate-solving software. There are several other software other than astrometry.net that can achieve this as well.

http://pinpoint.dc3.com/

http://www.astrosurf.com/pulgar/elbrus/elbrusin.htm

To name a few